# Moq runs overrided method but does not reach to the breakpoint of the method body

Tags: c#, moq

I mocked a class and passed the arguments as below :

```
var myClass = new Mock<MyClass>(a.Object, c.Object, b.Object);
```

Here is a definition of the `MyClass`

```
class MyClass : A
{
    public override void Execute(IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
       ....
    }
}

class A : AbstractClass
{
      public override void Execute()
       {
       }
}
```

I call the Execute method in unit test:

```
myClass.Object.Execute();
```

The problem is, it seems that it executes the method but it does not reach the break-point I made inside the body of `Execute` method in `MyClass`.

When I instantiate the `MyClass` without Moq and call the `Execute` it reaches the break-point.

**Update**

For more clarification, I already (before asking the question) tried to use `CallBase=true` and it did not work. I knew the philosophy of the Mock, and it is my curiosity of why it does not work when it is begin called differently!

Comment: The question is why do you want to use mock if you want to have the actual behavior? The philosophy behind the mock is different...

Comment: @Johnny At first step I want to know why it works in normal instantiation and why it acts differently in mock mode, then change it to adopt to what you call "philosophy" of the mock which I already knew about that !

Comment: Mock create proxy for each mocked type, notice only interface and virtual method could be mocked is because of that, then each call is intercepted and processed based on the setup behavior. As the answer says if you want to invoke the actual method then you should setup CallBase behaviour... If you want to Throw you could setup that if you want to return non-default value that is also possible.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here. Mocking an object with virtual methods creates a new mock that has overridden those methods with custom code, by default it does not call the original methods, at all. You say it works in "normal instantiation", do you mean "with the actual object"? Because that *should* work, that's just normal behavior, you execute the code, it hits the breakpoint. But if you mock the object and thus that method, only the mock method will execute, by default. You say you know "the philosophy of the mock", but I'm not entirely sure you understand what mocking is.

Comment: In any case, you need to post your actual code, you say "myClass.Object.Execute()", where did "Object" come from? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo is the problem that actually you setup `MyClass` but you got the results from `A` for that override method?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. if you look at the code carefully you would understand that myClass is of type Mock<MyClass> so I can access the Object from the instance !

Comment: @Johnny the code flow does not hit any break-point neither in MyClass nor A

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
myClass.Setup(m => m.Execute(It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>())).CallBase();
```

Or when you create an instance of your mock, pass this CallBase parameter to it.

```
myClass= new Mock<MyClass>(a.Object, c.Object, b.Object) { CallBase = true };
```

For more information you can look at [moq wiki](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) in part **Customizing Mock Behavior**.
Hope it will help you.

**UPD.**

Here is code that I have written to test your case. And I can say, that it hits breakpoint in myClass.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void Execute(IDictionary<string, object> parameters);
}

public class A : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Execute(IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
public class MyClass : A
{
    public override void Execute(IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestAbstractClass()
    {
        var myClass = new Mock<MyClass>() {CallBase = true};

        myClass.Object.Execute(new Dictionary<string, object>());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried it before posting the question here and it did not work.

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo, I updated my answer. Check it out. It works.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new project and tested your code and it works but mine still have problem. I noticed that MyClass derives from a class (Call it A) and A derives from the abstract class so I changed my question. Does it effect its behavior?

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo, I have tried with your hierarchy and it still can hit breakpoint in MyClass. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried your last update and it did not work this time and did not hit any breakpoint either in A or MyClass instances. I use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting if it changes any thing by the way.

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo, my code can't hit breakpoint in A class. But with MyClass it works in proper way.

Answer (score 1):

> my curiosity of why it does not work when it is begin called differently

**This is by design of the `moq`.**

---

As I have already said, mock create proxy for each mocked type, notice only interface, non sealed class and abstract\virtual method could be mocked is because of that it simply inherit base class, then each call is intercepted and processed based on the setup behavior. So, if you mock the class you will have the following:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(); // it is the instance of MyClass
var myClassMock = new Mock<MyClass>(); // it is the instance of MyClassProxy : MyClass
```

these types are different, if `myClass.Execute()` is invoked you will clearly call the imlementation but if you invoke `myClassMock.Object.Execute()` you will end up in the proxy class. The default behaviour of proxy class is to return `default(T)`, if you don't setup anything, but you could setup different behaviour e.g.:

- invoke base, in you case `MyClass`, by setting `CallBase`
- throw exception, `.Setup(...).Throws<TException>()`
- return non-default, `.Setup(...).Returns(value)`